# Twig Forms Using Laravel not working

Tags: laravel, twig, laravel-blade

I was using Blade, but I have now switched to Twig with help from [TwigBridge](https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge).

How can I get my form to render properly using Twig instead of Blade syntax?

This is my form;

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'survey.create')) !!}
  {!! Form::submit("Start survey", ['class' => "btn btn-lg btn-primary"]) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

What is it in Twig?

I tried just replacing all occurrences of `!!` with `{` (or`}`) or even `%` but that didn't work.

The error I get is;

> Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("end of print statement" expected)

Or;

> Unexpected "Form" tag (expecting closing tag for the "block" tag defined near line 4)

Answer (score 3):

For using Form or HTML tag, of blade.

If you're usign **Laravel 5.1** or below:

you have to use this package: **"illuminate/html":"5.0.*"**. For installation, refer [this](https://www.flynsarmy.com/2015/02/install-illuminatehtml-laravel-5/) link.

**or** if it is **Laravel 5.2** then use:

**"laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"** package.

Try this: `{{ form_start(form, {'method': 'GET'}) }}`

for more reference, view this [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html).

Comment: I already have that installed. And proof of that is that the form syntax above was working in blade.

Comment: Read this: https://octobercms.com/forum/post/suggestion-more-laravel-would-be-nice-what-do-you-think

Comment: this is now my error `Unknown "form_open" function`

Answer (score 0):

eg:
{{ form_open({'route':['link_resource', id ]}) }}
:
{{ form_close() }}

Form:: methods have snake_cased equivs as mentioned here:
https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge